# query optimisation with join on ordered data

Tags: optimization, join

My question concerns the optimization of a query sql.

My query retrieves a list of members and their last training.

To get the latest training I do a join on the result of a query returning a complete list of training for all members.

This query works but it is very slow, I'm really interrested if someone would have a solution for it to execute faster.

My query (about 16s):

```
SELECT 
    m.nom,
    m.prenom,
    m.ville,
    m.maj,
    mbf.libelle,
    mbf.datefin,
    m.id as idmb
FROM
    membres m
    LEFT JOIN (
        select *
        from membreform
        where idformation = 1
        order by datefin DESC
    ) as mbf ON mbf.idmembre = m.id
WHERE
    role > 0 AND visible = 1
group by m.id
ORDER BY m.maj DESC
limit 0 , 20
```

My data structure :

> membreform (1000 entries)

- `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
- `idmembre` int(11) NOT NULL,
- `libelle` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
- `idformation` int(11) NOT NULL,
- `datedebut` date NOT NULL,
- `datefin` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
- `descript` text NOT NULL,
- KEY `id` (`id`),
- KEY `idmembre` (`idmembre`),
- KEY `idformation` (`idformation`)

> membres (500 entries)

- `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
- `nom` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
- `prenom` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
- `ville` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
- `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
- `maj` datetime NOT NULL,
- `role` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
- PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
- KEY `role` (`role`),
- KEY `maj` (`maj`)

I tested this other way (about 0.40s) but I dont find that really clean

```
SELECT 
    m.nom,
    m.prenom,
    m.ville,
    m.maj,
    m.id as idmb,
    (select 
            libelle
        from
            membreform
        where
            idformation = 1
                AND m.id = membreform.idmembre
        order by datefin DESC
        limit 1
    ) libelle,
    (select 
            datefin
        from
            membreform
        where
            idformation = 1
                AND m.id = membreform.idmembre
        order by datefin DESC
        limit 1
    ) datefin
FROM
    membres m
WHERE
    role > 0 AND visible = 1
group by m.id
ORDER BY m.maj DESC
limit 0 , 20
```

I'm open to any suggestions because I am a bit stuck

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use temporary table to increase performace. E.g (MS SQL)
1 Step - Get the memberform data into temp table by adding all relevant where conditions

select *
INTO #TempMembreform 
from membreform
where idformation = 1 ...
order by datefin DESC

2 step - do the left outer join as you did in the above first example.
E.g.

```
SELECT 
    m.nom,
    m.prenom,
    m.ville,
    m.maj,
    mbf.libelle,
    mbf.datefin,
    m.id as idmb
FROM
    membres m
    LEFT JOIN #TempMembreForm as mbf 
        ON mbf.idmembre = m.id
WHERE
    role > 0 AND visible = 1
group by m.id
ORDER BY m.maj DESC
limit 0 , 20
```

3 Step - add NOLOCK keyword if the data is not mision crical (e.g. Bank tracnsactions )

```
select *
INTO #TempMembreform 
from membreform WITH(NOLOCK)
where idformation = 1
order by datefin DESC

SELECT 
    m.nom,
    m.prenom,
    m.ville,
    m.maj,
    mbf.libelle,
    mbf.datefin,
    m.id as idmb
FROM
    membres m with(nolock)
    LEFT JOIN #TempMembreForm as mbf 
        ON mbf.idmembre = m.id
WHERE
    role > 0 AND visible = 1
group by m.id
ORDER BY m.maj DESC
limit 0 , 20
```

[My profile](http://qwuizno.com/)

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer.

After a few more tests I could speed up the query by a simple modification> I specified fields in the join query (instead of *)> the execution takes 0.12s now :)
I am surprised that this simple change have such an impact, but in fact it works!